# Changing width of column on one page only

Tags: multicol

I'm trying to create a page with two columns, on one page only, the rest should be with only one column.
I've tried the package `multicol`and that solves one part of my problem which is to get a divider line between the columns. For that I use

```
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.5pt}
\def\columnseprulecolor{\color{orange}}
```

It seems like there is no way to change the width of the columns with `multicol`.
I've seen different approaches like using `minipage`but that removes my separator.

Is there any way to do this? I've been at it for a couple of hours now and can't seem to find a nice easy way to do it.

And I'm using the `latexmk -pdf file.tex` in linux to create my pdf's whatever that latex package is called.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}

\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.5pt}
\def\columnseprulecolor{\color{orange}}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
[
\section*{First Section}
Section title, spanning.
]
This is the left column that I want to be 0.3 of \textwidth

\columnbreak

And here is the right column with \textwidth 0.7
\end{multicols}

Something else here. The text should not be multicolumned in this part

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Do you mean `multicol` package?

Comment: The question title and `I'm trying to create a page with two columns, on one page only, the rest should be with only one column. I've tried the package` do not really match ;-)

Comment: How do you want the text to flow within the 2-column page? Should it naturally flow from left to right (mid-paragraph, say), or will you issue a manual `\columnbreak` to move text from left to right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `parcolumns` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{parcolumns}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{parcolumns}[colwidths={1=.3\textwidth},rulebetween=true]{2}
\colchunk{% left column
  \sloppy
  \kant[1]
}
\colchunk{% right column
  \kant[2-3]
}
\end{parcolumns}

\end{document}
```

If you want a colored rule, you have to patch a command

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{parcolumns}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\pc@placeboxes}
  {\vrule}{\begingroup\color{orange}\vrule width 1pt\endgroup}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{parcolumns}[colwidths={1=.3\textwidth},rulebetween=true]{2}
\colchunk{% left column
  \sloppy
  \kant[1]
}
\colchunk{% right column
  \kant[2-3]
}
\end{parcolumns}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, it seems that a simple `minipage` could do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr.3\textwidth-\tabcolsep-.5pt}
\sloppy
\kant*[1]
\end{minipage}%
\hfill\begingroup\color{orange}\vrule width 1pt\endgroup\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr.7\textwidth-\tabcolsep-.5pt}
\kant*[2-3]
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

The output is essentially the same.

Comment: For the sake of your answer I tried both examples, and they gave the exact same output and does exactly what I want them to do! The minipage seems to be the best choice (less code). Thanks